# What's a doorway that doesn't have a door called?

Tags: architecture

A doorway? passageway? archway? lintel? soffit?

I have to label one on an architectural drawing, and it occurred to me that there may be a more technically accurate term for it than "passageway" or "archway."

Don't know if this question is more appropriate for Home Improvement or the English Language and Usage site.  */shrug*

Comment: How about "opening"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you were just using the dictionary definitions, it would be called a "*doorway*".

> **Doorway**
>   1. the passage or opening into a building, room, etc., commonly closed and opened by a door;  portal.
>   2. a means of access: a doorway to success.
>
> **Door**
>   1. a movable, usually solid, barrier for opening and closing an entranceway, cupboard, cabinet, or the like, commonly turning on
>   hinges or sliding in grooves.
>   2. a doorway: to go through the door.
>   3. the building, house, etc., to which a door belongs: My friend lives two doors down the street.
>   4. any means of approach, admittance, or access: the doors to learning.
>   5. any gateway marking an entrance or exit from one place or state to another:  at heaven's door.
>
> **Passageway**
>   1. a way  for passing into, through, or out of something, as within a building or between buildings; a corridor, hall, alley, catwalk, or
>   the like.
>   2. a corridor on a ship.
>
> **Archway**
>   1. an entrance or passage under an arch.
>   2. a covering or enclosing arch.
>
> **Lintel**
>   1. a horizontal architectural member supporting the weight above an opening, as a window or a door.
>
> **soffit**
>   1. the underside of an architectural feature, as a beam, arch, ceiling, vault, or cornice.
>
> [Source](http://dictionary.reference.com/)

Since you're dealing with architectural drawings, you'll probably want to use ["*Cased Opening*"](http://www.ehouseplans.com/blueprints/blueprints.html#10) (or "*Arched Opening*" if the top of the opening should have an arch). Which would be drawn on a blueprint using this symbol.

[image: Cased opening symbol]

A cased opening is a doorway that is trimmed out, but does not contain a door. If you just want an opening in the wall without trim, you could just call it an "*Opening*", or "*archway*". It would look like this on a blueprint.

[image]

Comment: The phrase *cased opening* is based on the term *casing* that refers to the vertical and horizontal molding facing each of the rooms the opening joins. (for Bonus Points: the three broad molding pieces that face into the opening itself are called *jambs*.)

Comment: Yeah, cased opening. But what's it called if it's not cased? Like it just has finished drywall wrapping around the framing, with no finish carpentry? I'm inclined to call it a framed opening, but that seems confusing.

Comment: I think *doorway* is often used even when there is no door. An alternative might be *entryway* or even *portal* but that is usually used for grand entrances.

Answer (score 5):

Chief Architect software calls door-sized openings without casings "archways" regardless of the shape of the top of the opening.

I had an archway that was a plain old rectangle in my last renovation and all the trades knew exactly what I meant when I called it that.

Comment: Frequent misuse does not equal proper use. By definition, in archway requires an arch.

Comment: When miscommunication can lead to costly mistakes as it so often does in construction, I favor language that is likely to be correctly understood to that which is "proper."

Answer (score 4):

It's a cased opening if it's finished, otherwise we call it a drywall opening.

Answer (score 1):

My choice would be portal.  It signifies you can get from one room to the other.

Comment: The term portal is reserved for 'extravagant' openings.

Comment: I stepped through a temporary portal in the space/time continuum and found myself on this DIY space, how do i find that portal again?